# greek url conversion and trim unwated numbers and symbols

Tags: php, wordpress

This problem is little complicated since i'm newbee to php encoding.
My site uses utf-8 encoding.

After a lot of tests, i found some solution. I use this kind of code:

```
function chr_conv($str)
{
    $a=array with pattern('%CE%B2','%CE%B3','%CE%B4','%CE%B5' etc..);
    $b=array with replacement characters(a,b,c,d, etc...);
    return str_replace($a, $b2, $str);
}

function replace_old($str)
{
    $a1 = array ('index.php','/http://' etc...);
    $a2 = array with replacement characters('','' etc...);
    return str_replace($a1, $a2, $str);
}

function sanitize($url)
{
    $url= replace_old(replace_old($url));
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url = preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/[?]/', '', $url);
    $url = substr($url,1);

    return $url;
}

function wbz404_process404()
{
    $options = wbz404_getOptions();
    $urlRequest = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = chr_conv($urlRequest);
    $requestedURL = replace_old(replace_old($url));
    $requestedURL .= wbz404_SortQuery($urlParts);

    //Get URL data if it's already in our database
    $redirect = wbz404_loadRedirectData($requestedURL);

    echo sanitize($requestedURL);
    echo "</br>";
    echo $requestedURL;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

When incoming url is:

> /content.php?147-%CE%A8%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%B9-%CE%BC%CE%B5-%CF%80%CF%81%CE%AC%CF%83%CE%B1%28%CE%A7%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%BC%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BA%29";

I get:

> /content.php?147-psari-me-prasa-choumplik

I want only:

> /psari-me-prasa-choumplik

without the `content.php?147-` before URL.
BUT the most important problem is that I get ENDLESS LOOP instead of correct URL.

What am i doing wrong?

Have in mind that `.htaccess` solution won't work since i have a `lighttpd` server, not `Apache`.

Comment: I am not sure by looking at this why it's becoming an endless loop. I would recommend putting in some debug echo statements and see if there is a function that is called more than a few times. At least put an echo statement showing the result of the previous line in ever other wbz404_process404() line to see how far it gets through that function before it gets the value ENDLESS LOOP.

Answer (score 0):

If you need

I am assuming it's not always ?147- that you need to skip. But always after the first hyphen. In which case, before the echo add the following:

```
$requestedURL = substr($requestedURL, strrpos( $requestedURL , '-') +1 );
```

This will search for the position of the first hyphen and return that, add one so you skip the hyphen itself, and use that to cut the $requestedURL string up after the hyphen to the end of the string.

If it's always /content.php?127- then replace strrpos( $requestedURL , '-') +1 with the number 17.

Comment: Yes, i want to ellininate the "/content.php?XXX-" where XXX = number from 001-999. When i run my code, i get endless loop redirection error.